# Unwrap degrees in pandas linearly

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with x as time and y as degrees (blue line). 
[image: Plot]

I want to unwrap the degrees such that first 360 deg is 360 deg, the second 360 deg is 720, the third 360 deg is 1080 and so on (orange line).

I can do this using for-loops and if conditions but I am looking for an elegant solution such that I can have this unwrapped data as a new column in the pandas dataframe.

Note: The t is not equi-sampled

Answer (score 0):

I made up some crude data to show how it can be done.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'deg_wrapped': [10,80,150,220,300,20,90,170,240,300,360,50,150,220,290]})
# get row to row differences, fill NA at start with first degree value
df['diffs'] = df.deg_wrapped.diff().fillna(df.deg_wrapped) 
# unwrap at jump points, assuming monotonic data
df.loc[df.diffs < 0, 'diffs'] = 360 - df.deg_wrapped.shift(1) + df.deg_wrapped
df['deg_unwrapped'] = df.diffs.cumsum()
```

yields

```
    deg_wrapped  diffs  deg_unwrapped
0            10   10.0           10.0
1            80   70.0           80.0
2           150   70.0          150.0
3           220   70.0          220.0
4           300   80.0          300.0
5            20   80.0          380.0   <--- jump point
6            90   70.0          450.0
7           170   80.0          530.0
8           240   70.0          600.0
9           300   60.0          660.0
10          360   60.0          720.0
11           50   50.0          770.0   <--- jump point
12          150  100.0          870.0
13          220   70.0          940.0
14          290   70.0         1010.0
```

This assumes that your degree values are increasing monotonically except for the jumps from 360 to 0 degrees. If that is not the case, you can adjust `df.diffs < 0` accordingly.